# Zend Framework: How to unset data rows in a Zend_Db_Table_Rowset object

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I would like to iterate over the data rows stored in a Zend_Db_Table_Rowset object and then drop/unset some of the rows, if they don't fulfil certain criteria.

I could use toArray() to get only the data rows from the object and then it would be easy to unset the rows I don't need. But since I want to keep my object for further use I don't want to do that.

Of course one solution would be to adjust my query in order to retrieve only what I need, but that's not possible in this scenario. At least I wouldn't know how.

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
foreach ($rowset as $key => $row)
{
    if (!$condition == satisfied)
    {
        unset($rowset[$key]);
    }
}
```

And of course it doesn't work, since there is no $rowset[$key]... the data is stored in a subarray [_data:protected] but unset $rowset[_data:protected][$key] didn't work either.

Maybe my conception of a rowset object (or the representation of objects in general) is not mature enough to understand what I'm doing. Any clarification and tips would be welcome!

[EDIT] 
$row->delete is NOT an option, I don't want to delete the row from the database!
I don't want to create an array first, if I wanted to I would just do $rowset->toArray()
[/EDIT]

**Solution**: I ended up doing what I thought I wasn't able too, meaning I integrated everything into the initial query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [custom Rowset class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.extending.row-rowset)

This class would have then access to the protected $_rows stored internally, and you could add a public method to applying your filtering

Comment: I ended up doing what I thought I wasn't able too, meaning I integrated everything into the query. But thanks for the custom rowset input which I will certainly need at one point.

Answer (score 6):

Example method for your [custom rowset class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.extending.row-rowset):

```
public function removeFromRowset($id) {
    foreach ($this->_rows as $i => $v) {
        if ($v->id == $id) { // found Row we want to remove
            unset($this->_rows[$i]); // delete both rowset
            unset($this->_data[$i]); // and original data
            break; // not necessary to iterate any more
        }
    }
    $this->_data = array_values($this->_data); // reindex both arrays (otherwise it breaks foreach etc.)
    $this->_rows = array_values($this->_rows);
    $this->_count = count($this->_data); // don't forget to update items count!
}
```

It iterate through your Rowset, finds Row according to its id (supposing "id" is unique identifier) and than remove it from the Rowset.

**Please note this doesn't delete the row from database, it just removes it from the Rowset!**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a way to do this. You could first create an array and then modify the array.

```
$rows = array();
foreach($rowset as $row)
{
     $rows[$row->id] = $row;
}

foreach ($rows as $key => $row)
{
     if(!$condition == satisfied)
     {
         unset($rows[$key]);
     }
}
```

Not the most efficient thing  to do but it works.

Comment: nope, I need the object to be healthy. and creating an array goes easy with $rowset->toArray()

Comment: $rowset->toArray() doesn't produce row objects. It returns the whole rowset as an array. That's why I didn't use it.

Comment: The custom rowset class above is probably your best bet.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the delete() method on the individual row object.

```
foreach ($rowset as $row)
{
    if (!$condition == satisfied)
    {
       $row->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: delete is destructive.  The row will be deleted from the table.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear but I don't want to delete the row from the table, I just want to remove it from the object!!

Comment: Please accept my apologies for not understanding what you were wanting to do.  As dcaunt suggested, and smack0007 affirmed, using a custom rowset would be the best option.